# Is there a name for this method of proof?

Tags: proof-writing, induction, terminology

If I want to prove that some statement $P(n,m)$ is true for all $n, m \in \mathbb{N}$, I can do this by showing that:

1. $P(1, 1)$
2. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}: P(1, n) \implies P(1, n+1)$
3. $\forall n, m \in \mathbb{N}: P(n, m) \implies P(n+1, m)$

Is there a name for this type of proof?

Comment: That is a proof by induction

Comment: @Sorfosh I feel like OP is familiar with regular old induction given the tags for the question. However we see two inductions in the post: I feel like the OP is asking if there is a term for such a type of induction. Anyhow I feel like this specific type of induction might be "double induction." I did see some variants in this paper (http://faculty.wwu.edu/sarkara/ph18.pdf) but I'm not an expert in the matter so grain of salt. **EDIT:** Or perhaps as Hagen von Eitzen answered, it might be a nested induction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called induction.

Or you may call it two nested inductions: With (1) and (2), you show that $P(1,m)$ holds for all $m\in \Bbb N$, by induction on $m$. Then with this and $(3)$, you show by induction on $n$ that $P(n,m)$ holds for all $n$ (where $m\in\Bbb N$ is arbitrary!)